# Non-Working C# code with seemingly no errors

Tags: c#, html, css, sql-insert, insert-into

So I have a problem with performing a INSERT INTO statement. Below you see the code I am using and it will not perform the action it is asked to do, I have tried so many things yet it still does not work.

```
    public IActionResult Submit()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Submit(string inpTitle, string inpContent )
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(Startup.ConStr))
            {
                con.Open(); string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Submissions (Title, Content, SubDate, SubUserID) VALUES(@Title, @Content, @SubDate, @SubUserID)";
                using (SqliteCommand com = new SqliteCommand(strSQL, con))
                {
                    com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Title", inpTitle));
                    com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Content", inpContent));
                    com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@SubDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy -MM-dd")));
                    com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@SubUserID", HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID")));
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = ".";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = ex.Message;
        }
        ViewBag.Error = ".";
        return View();
    }
```

The database table I want to insert that into has 5 columns, 4 of which are listed above and the 5th one being a primary, autoincrement key.

This is the code I have on the Submit page:

```
<div id="side">
<h3>@ViewBag.Error</h3>
<h1>Title</h1>
<input name="inpTitle" type="text" />
<h1>Contents</h1>
<textarea name="inpContent" rows="25" cols="75"></textarea>
&nbsp;
<div>
    <button style="width: 150px;" name="submit" type="submit"><h3>Submit</h3></button>
</div>
<p style="color: white;">@ViewBag.Message</p>
```

CSS used in this:

```css
#side {
    width: 600px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You never execute the Command.

Comment: And your catch statement is ineffective, the message is overwritten with `"."` in the next line.

Comment: I was more worried about it not executing at all, but I too realised the invalid placement of that statement and already changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you accidentally forgot to put the execution of your command in the above code, but if it's not an accident, you'll need to actually execute the command:
`com.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: I feel so stupid, I guess I must have forgotten it in the sea of parameters I have. I have had many of these derp moments with coding in the last few days lol, I guess that is what happens when you work on a website almost non-stop.

Comment: It happens to the best of us ^^ Good luck!